# Como fazer update do banco de dados com SELECT Sum

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer o `update` de uma tabela somando dois valores (dinheiro + depositado), assim obtendo o *total*. Esse total eu já tenho utilizando o código

```
Select SUM(dinheiro)+(depositado) total from usuarios WHERE id=1
```

Porém eu queria colocar o valor acima na tabela e eu não to conseguindo assim:

```
UPDATE usuarios SET total=(Select SUM(dinheiro)+(depositado) total from usuarios WHERE id=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim?

```
UPDATE usuarios SET total = dinheiro + depositado WHERE id = 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Add.sql).

Entenda as colunas como variáveis. Não tem que fazer nada maluco para obter seus valores. Basta pegar a variável que naquela linha terá o valor da coluna, nada além disto. Não tente usar coisas sem conhecer. Vai no simples. O que isto está fazendo é pegar o valor de duas colunas, somando, e armazenando em outra coluna. Simples assim. neste caso será feito apenas no usuário que tenha o `id` igual a 1. Se tirar esse `where` será feito em todos os usuários, cada usuário terá sua própria soma isolada das demais. Se sabe programar imperativamente em linguagem de programação é como se fosse um `for`. Quando coloca o `where` é como se tivesse um `if` dentro desse `for`. Se o banco de dados foi modelado adequadamente será muito rápido porque ele tem otimização. Se não souber modelar e tiver muitos dados será trágico.

O primeiro `select` não faz o menor sentido, ele funciona por coincidência.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Será mais trágico funcionar bem e achar que é assim que se faz. O ideal é aprender os conceitos antes de fazer qualquer coisa. Ao contrário do que se prega por aí programação não é fácil.

Além disso saber e entender e comunicar o seu problema é algo que vem até antes da programação.